# Logging into Guest user

Tags: macbook-pro

When i try to log in into the Guest user it appears like this.[image: warning] And if I restart and logging into it, it shows up only safari.

**How can I log in normally to the Guest user account?**

Comment: from an admin account, try: System Preferences > Users & Groups > Other Users > Guest User and tell us how it is set up.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is how can i log in normally into guest user.

Comment: @GEdgar If i turn off the fire vault from security and privacy thats the time secure safari mode turns off. But is it safe to turn off fire vault?

Comment: The image you show is the normal setup for a guest account. If the answer provided isn't sufficient, feel free to edit in the body of the question what requirements for normal are. Perhaps you just want to have two accounts on your Mac once it boots past the FileVault limited boot?

Answer (score 2):

To disable this (I'm assuming that's what you want):

1. Open System Preferences
2. Security & Privacy
3. Advanced
4. The option you're looking for is: 'Disable restarting to Safari when screen is locked'

Some have reported that disabling Find my Mac from System Preferences will also fix your issue, but the solution above is preferable.